# Constant curvature and parallel curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $(M,g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. We say that this is a *space of constant curvature* if the sectional curvature $K(p,S)=\frac{\langle R(X,Y)X,Y\rangle}{X^2Y^2-\langle X,Y\rangle^2}$ is constant for all nondegenerate $2$-directions $S\le T_pM$ for all $p\in M$ ($X,Y\in S$ is any basis for the $2$-direction).

It is well-known and is quite easy to show that an equivalent condition to this is that $$ R_{ijkl}=K\left(g_{ik}g_{jl}-g_{il}g_{jk}\right), $$where $K$ is a constant.

It follows from this that $\nabla R=0$ or in coordinates $R_{ijkl;m}=0$, i.e. the curvature tensor is parallel.

I always had the impression that this is also an equivalent condition, i.e $$ R_{ijkl;m}=0\Longleftrightarrow (M,g)\text{ is of constant curvature}, $$ however I do not know any proof and I skimmed through quite a few books on Riemannian geometry both modern and old-school and I did not see this statement or a proof of it.

---

So my question is, if one is given a pseudo-Riemannian space with parallel curvature tensor ($R_{ijkl;m}=0$) does it follow that the space is also a space of constant sectional curvature?

If so I'd like to know a reference where this is proven in this direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implication does not go the other way. All [locally symmetric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) have parallel curvature and there are locally symmetric spaces of nonconstant sectional curvature, such as the [Fubini-Study metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric) on $\mathbb{CP}^n$ for $n\ge 2$.